# why is my center <div> is not aligned with my left <div> and right <div>?

Tags: css, html, center

I'm trying to put three div together. One is on the left, one is in the middle, and one is on the right.

However, I'm experiencing a problem that the middle  is not aligned properly.

My current HTML code:

```
 <div class="three_contents">
     <div class="left">Left</div>
     <div class="right">Right</div>
     <div class="center">Center</div>
 </div>
```

My current CSS code:

```
.three_contents{
width: 900px;
border: 0px solid #000;
}

.left{float: left;
margin-top: 25px;
width: 290px;
height: 290px;}

.right{float: right;
margin-top: 25px;
width: 290px;
height: 290px;}

.center{display:block;
margin: 25px auto;
width: 290px;
height: 290px;}
```

However, when I add a 1px border in the the three_contents div, and the middle div is aligned. I have attached two screenshots and hopefully someone can help me to resolve this issue.  Thanks a lot.

Problem with the middle div isn't aligned:

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/250sg3p.png]

After I add the 1px border, and the middle div is aligned:

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/vy9lqq.png]

Comment: Please show what you've already tried with CSS.

Comment: post your HTML and CSS code with which you are having problem.

Comment: You're also going to have to explain what _"middle is not aligned properly."_ is supposed to mean.

Comment: Do you want column like layout? Or anything else?

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing the question. Please review the question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the margin only on the center `div`. Like so:

```
.three_contents
{
    width: 900px;
    border: 0;
}

.left
{
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
}

.right
{
    float: right;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;}

.center
{
    margin: 25px auto;
    display:block;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
}
```

I made a fiddle to show you this: http://jsfiddle.net/stakL/1/

**EDIT:** To be sincere, I also don't quite understand *why* it happens. But I can see that the `margin-top` property set on the left and right `div`'s was taking the middle `div`'s top position as the reference point to apply that margin.

On other words, the center `div` was 25px from the top, and the left and right `div`'s were 25px from the **middle** `div`'s top.

Comment: It works now. Could you explain why if I put the "margin-top" in the left div and right div, and it causes this problem? Also, when I only use one margin in the center div, why the left and right will be aligned?